# "Разный" vs "различный"

Tags: значения, словоупотребление

What is the difference between the adjectives "разный" and "различный". Are they used in different situations?

Answer (score 1):

These are synonyms, and are interchangeable in many situations. *Разный* is more like *different*, whereas *различный* is more like *various*. When you're contrasting two objects, разный is preferable. For example:

> У нас с сестрой глаза разного цвета (My sister and I have different eye colors)
>
> <strike>У нас с сестрой глаза различного цвета</strike> (<strike>My sister and I have various eye colors</strike>)

Comment: "У нас с сестрой глаза различного цвета" is a perfectly fine sentence, but it would literally mean that for both of you, one eye has a different color than the other eye (глаза различного цвета = гетерохромия)- an entirely different meaning than 'various'.

Comment: @Peteris: You're right, that meaning didn't occur to me. This is fun :)

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics the term различный is used more often, corresponding to "distinct" (not "various", as Armen writes) instead of "different",  e.g., Пусть p и q различные простые числа (Let p and q be distinct primes).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find the difference is to try to replace them with each other in different contexts and see what happens ;-)

- `У нас разные мнения` - our views are different but most likely they do not contradict
- `У нас различные мнения` - our views very likely contradict each other
- `Занят разными/различными делами`
- `два различных предмета` - from an example [here](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), you can see the opposition more clearly when 2 is used

So my conclusion is that these are synonyms but you should consider `различный` if you want to underline the **opposition / contrast / contradiction / conflict** of some qualities or features.

Think of `различный` as of a word in the same semantic field as the words: `различаться, различие`. In Enlish it is **differ, different, difference** while `разный` is more like **various, not similar** but can also mean **different** because `разный` has a wider semantic field and is a more frequent word.